# Remove single space between two characters in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Remove single space between two characters in notepad++

that means example

1. A. B.

i want this

1. A.B.

in notepad++ using reqex

Comment: Yes, [Notepad++ supports Regex find/replace](https://datacadamia.com/ide/notepad/replace). What have you tried so far? It should be something similar to Find: `(\d+\. [A-Z]\.)( )([A-Z]\.)`, Replace: `\1\3`.

Comment: Why do you remove the space before the `B` but not before the `A`? Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66442541/edit) and add real example and expected result.